# Postgres convert to columns from string json

Tags: postgresql, json

I am running postgresql 14.4. I have a table with 2 fields:

```
id   data_product(varchar)
---  ------------
1    [{"product_id":1,"product_code":"A1","distribution_ratio":40},{"product_id":2,"product_code":"A2","distribution_ratio":60}]
.........
```

I need to move the data to a new table with fields like:

```
id   product_id   product_code   distribution_ratio
---  ----------   ------------   ------------------
1        1             A1                 40
1        2             A2                 60
.........
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jsonb_to_recordset function as follows:

```
select id,extracted_data.*
from your_table
join lateral jsonb_to_recordset(data_product) 
as extracted_data ("product_id" int ,"product_code" text,"distribution_ratio" int) on true
```

Comment: thanks. i found a way.
    
SELECT id, code, status, product_id, product_code, distribution_ratio
FROM template_categories tc, json_to_recordset(tc.data_product::json) AS x(product_id int, product_code text, distribution_ratio float);

I tried using your way but it didn't work. I am running postgresql.